# How can I segment out disconnected regions of nodes (arc nodes?) in a graph network?

Tags: python, graph, network-programming, networkx, graph-algorithm

The image below shows the Node-Edge graph.

[image]

I would like to segment out clusters of nodes into separate graphs as shown below. Nodes 4, 5 are not part of the reset of the graph. How can I do this algorithmically for an arbitrary graph network?

[image]

I am using python 3.8 and windows 10.

Comment: why edges only attach to one node in the matrix and what's wrong with `nx.algorithms.components.connected_components`?

Comment: I dont think nx works with py3.8, scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components but scipy has a same implementation

Comment: `networkx` 2.5 works with Python 3.6 and up (including 3.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components.html